# Root directory en producción

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, despliegue

Estoy tratando de desplegar mi proyecto el cual tiene un frontend en Reactjs y un backend en Node js. No estoy seguro cuál es el directorio raíz y tal vez por eso el despliegue arroja errores. Esta es la estructura del proyecto.: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al interior de la carpeta "server" está el archivo index.js que es el backend
¿Podría alguien decirme cuál sería el directorio raíz?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El directorio raíz de tu proyecto está exáctamente en `programador-frontend`

Digamos que el directorio raíz es la primera carpeta donde se aloja el proyecto (donde están siempre los `node_modules` o el `package.json`)